# How to remove duplicate object after appending new one in swift

Tags: swift

Im new in swift and I've gathered a lot of data from here together to build my small project. At this place I'm a bit lost and would like to ask you this:

I would like to save a color and the depending mixing ratio into a object (which I plan to save then in the phone memory, but I'm not so far now). This I can do without any problems. But when I add the same color with a other mixing ratio I would like to delete the previous created (same) color.

That's the point. I dont know how to delete the previous one.
What I have till now (greatful this forum) is this:

Init stuff:

```
class main{

    var colorCollection:[color]!

    init() {
        colorCollection = [color]()
    }

    func addColor(iColorName:color) {
        colorCollection.append(iColorName)
    }

}

class color{

    var colorName:String!

    var ingredient:[ingredients]!

    init() {
        ingredient = [ingredients]()
    }

    func addIngredient(iIngredient:String) {

        var tmpIngredient = ingredients()
        tmpIngredient.ingredient = iIngredient

        ingredient.append(tmpIngredient)

    }

    func arrayCount(){
        println("Ingredients   : \(ingredient.count)")
    }
}

class ingredients{
    var ingredient:String!
}


var CL = main()
var ingredient = color()
```

So from here I'm creating the objects like so:

```
CL.addColor(ingredient)

ingredient.colorName = "RED"
ingredient.addIngredient("20 ml: Magenta")
ingredient.addIngredient("21 ml: Yellow")

ingredient = color()
```

After a few wile the user decide to change the color in the GUI and I create a new object:

```
CL.addColor(ingredient)

ingredient.colorName = "RED"
ingredient.addIngredient("20 ml: Magenta")
ingredient.addIngredient("22 ml: Yellow")
ingredient.addIngredient("51 ml: Black")

ingredient = color()
```

Printing it:

```
for color in BN.colorCollection {
    println("COLOR: \(color.colorName)")

    for ingr in color.ingredient {
        println(" -> Ingredient   : \(ingr.ingredient)")
    }
    color.arrayCount()
}
```

And the result is:

```
COLOR: RED
 -> Ingredient   : 20 ml: Magenta
 -> Ingredient   : 21 ml: Yellow
Ingredients   : 2
COLOR: RED
 -> Ingredient   : 20 ml: Magenta
 -> Ingredient   : 22 ml: Yellow
 -> Ingredient   : 51 ml: Black
Ingredients   : 3
```

So as you see, there are two RED's where I would like to have only the newly created one. Any help would be amazing. Thx

Comment: There is so much wrong with this code ... Please read the Swift book first.

Comment: ...starting with not obeying the naming conventions which make your code hard to read for others.

Comment: so most likely (and simply) you're just after a delete method for arrays which is e.g. `removeAt(index)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only have to modify the `addColor` function to this:

```
func addColor(iColorName:color) {
    var pos = -1

    // Find if a color with the same name is already in the array
    for (index, color) in enumerate(colorCollection) {
        if (color.colorName == iColorName.colorName) {
            pos = index
            break
        }
    }

    if (pos > -1) {
        // If found, replace its with the new color object
        colorCollection[pos] = iColorName
    } else {
        // Otherwise, add it
        colorCollection.append(iColorName)
    }
}
```

But that won't do what you need right away. Because your code is *really* bad.

---

#### What's wrong with your code:

1. Crazy naming convention: `colorName` is a string but `iColorName` is an object of type `color`; `ingredients` is a class but `ingredient` is an array; later, you define a variable `ingredient` as type `color` however `iIngredient` is a string! I wanna throw a book at you now!

2.
The color has not been properly set before being sent to another object.

```
var ingredient = color()
CL.addColor(ingredient)         // no name and no ingredients
ingredient.colorName = "RED"
ingredient.addIngredient("20 ml: Magenta")
ingredient.addIngredient("21 ml: Yellow")
```

The object may clone the color before adding it to an array, in which case your subsequent statements will have no effect upon it. You should finish setting up your object before passing it to another object:

```
var ingredient = color()
ingredient.colorName = "RED"
ingredient.addIngredient("20 ml: Magenta")
ingredient.addIngredient("21 ml: Yellow")
CL.addColor(ingredient)         // now you are good!
```

3. Color with no name: the `colorName` property is defined as optional, which let you do what you did. But is it really expected that a color may have no name?

Comment: Thank you very much for this. I will now take a deep look into the class definitions and the naming conventions. I appreciate your help very well and Im sorry for this trouble code! I hope I can once code like you guys!